# Difference between setMinWidth and setMinimumWidth in ToggleButton

Tags: java, android, user-interface

I have a `ToggleButton` in my xml with `android:min_width=128dp`. All works fine, but I have one place, where I should remove this restriction by code.

Surprisingly, `ToggleButton` have TWO methods for this. Documentation says nothing about the difference between them, and what is more strange, I have to use both methods to make my button smaller. If I use one of them (any), it doesn't work.

So I wonder, what is the difference and what is the right way to set minimum width for toggle button from the code.

Comment: For regular buttons, you need to set both (figured out by experimentation) -- I expect this to be the same for toggle buttons or any other text view. Didn't try to figure out why there are two methods, one declared on View and the other on TextView.